# How to call a function from within a function?

Tags: javascript

how can you put a function in a function?

```
do_something(){
    alert('do something');
}

also_do_something = function(){
    alert('also do something');
};

inp.onclick = function(){
    do_something();

    // this don't work
    also_do_something;
};
```

Comment: Yo dawg we heard you like functions....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To call a function, you must add the parentheses :

```
inp.onclick = function(){
    do_something();

    also_do_something();
};
```

Comment: dough.. I didn't even think of that.. hehe

Answer (score 3):

`also_do_something` is a function reference, you don't call that, you just get it. If you want to call, use `also_do_something ()`

Answer (score 2):

to call a function, you need to add the parenthesis:

```
inp.onclick = function(){
    do_something();

    // this don't work
    also_do_something();
};
```

would be interesting to hear what made you put parenthesis in `do_something()` and not in `also_do_something` ?

Comment: @nEEbz... it might have to do with declaring `also_do_something = function()` thinking maybe that all you need to do is invoke `also_do_something`? I don't know what was going on though @clarkk's head though... just a guess